# select data from table1 but need table2 as condition in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to do:

```
 select column1
 from db1.table1
 where db1.table1.column2 = db2.table2.column1.
```

In this case, the error message is:

> unknown column: db2.table2.column1

My setting for the database 1 and 2 is correct, just don't know how to write the query in this case.

Comment: Just to make sure, both of the tables are in different databases?

Comment: add table2 in your select part, you need to select the tables before conditioning them. also it seems your using 2 databases?

Comment: Are you going to accept one of these answers? Or do none of them work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t1.column1
from db1.table1 t1
join db2.table2 t2 on t1.column2 = t2.column1
```

You'll notice that this query uses the more modern, and preferable, `join table on condition` syntax

Comment: You might want to qualify the `column1` to a table as the name may exist in both.

Answer (score 1):

You need to list `db2.table2` in the `FROM` clause. Assuming you want `column1` from `db.table1`:

```
select t1.column1
from db1.table1 t1, db2.table2 t2
where t1.column2 = t2.column1
```

Otherwise you cannot use them in the `WHERE` clause.

If you prefer using the `join ... on` syntax (called explicit join), then check Bohemian's answer.

For a discussion about which syntax to pick, see [Explicit vs implicit SQL joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)

Comment: if you have the same columns in table1 and table2 you can use table1.column1

Answer (score 0):

```
select column1
from db1.table1, db2.table2
where db1.table1.column2  = db2.table2.column1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    db1.col1,
    db2.col2
FROM
    db1.tb1 
LEFT JOIN
    db2.tb2 ON db2.tb2.col1 = db1.tb1.col2
```